# Basic Understanding of derivatives as a rate of change

Tags: calculus, derivatives, area

I am teaching myself calculus and trying to understand derivatives from a physics point of view. I am faced with this question: the edge of a square is being enlarged at $ 
2 \frac{cm}{sec}$. What is the rate of change of the area when the edge is 6 cm long. The solution in the book (Serge Lang, A first course in Calculus, 5th ed) is as follows:

$A = x^2 \\
\frac{dA}{dx} = 2x$

Using chain rule:

$ \frac{dA} {dt} =\frac{dA} {dx} * \frac{dx} {dt} \\
= 2x * 2 = 4x $

When the edge is 6: $\frac{dA}{dt} = 4*6 = 24$.

My main issue is that intuitively I had assume I can do the following:

At time $t_1, A_1 = x^2$

$\\ $At time $t_1+1, A_2 = (x+2)(x+2) =
x^2 + 4x + 4$

Then $\frac {dA}{dt}= \frac{A_2 - A_1} {t_1 +1 - t_1} = 4x+4$

Which does not match the answer, also, calculating difference of area when edge goes from 4 to 6 is 36 - 16 = 20 and not 24.

I would like to understand what was wrong in my logic. Also I considered this might be due to the fact that I am taking a long interval ( 1 sec. and derivatives evaluate the rate of change at exactly the point of change). But again the rate which we are using is defined as 2 $\frac {cm}{sec}$,we don't have any information about how it grows in shorter intervals, so I don't know if it make sense to think of shorter intervals than 1 second.

When I googled about derivates from definition are different from formulas I came against something called backward and forward differences and centered differences, it seems to be related to discrete mathematics which I have no experience with yet. But using the idea to evaluate the derivate at the center yields:

$(x+1)(x+1) - (x-1)(x-1) = 4x$

This also is correct as difference between 49 and 25.
Maybe someone can shade light on this?
(I guess same result can be reached if we take two differences, one forward and one backward and average them on the time interval of 2 second).

Also one final remark that confused me, the fact I can evaluate the area when $x = 5$ and $x = 6$ is based on the initial condition of the length of the edge. That is, is not there a hidden assumption that the increase is uniform everywhere during this one second? What I mean to point out is that if the edge was being increased in pulses and not uniformly then I can not assume that $x-1$ and $x+1$ (despite having a distance of 2 separating them) are actually legal to evaluate, because the only information I was given that $x_{next } = x_{old} + 2$ for every second that passes

Thanks.

Comment: please edit your post to put  dollar symbol \$ around your math expressions. This makes the difference between writing (x+1)(x+1)-(x-1)(x-1) versus $(x+1)(x+1)-(x-1)(x-1)$

Comment: It is not very difficult to format your question properly; that way you are likely to get better attention. A step in that direction is to start by enclosing math symbols in pairs of $ symbols.

Comment: I made a few suggested edits using $ but too much to rewrite entire post. Welcome to SE, take a look around at some questions and answers to get a sense of how well-posed questions go and how they look.  Many times, new users just ask a question expect answer and do not provide context or show what they have tried (you are definitely NOT in this group).

Comment: Finite differences are not the same as derivatives. You should treat time as a real number.

Comment: You do know how fast the edge is moving at intervals smaller than one second, the rate of change of the edge is 2 cm/sec *continuously* for all time.

Comment: Your fallacy is in assuming that the change in area with respect to time is constant. If $A=x^2$ then $\frac{dA}{dt}=2x\frac{dx}{dt}$ which means that the area changes faster as the length of the sides increase. The point of derivatives is that we are taking an instantaneous rate of change, not an average rate of change which you attempted to do by taking the difference in areas at two discrete times one second apart.

Comment: Adding to what @JohnDouma said, recall that the derivative is defined as the limit $f'(x) = \lim_{d \rightarrow 0} \frac{f(x+d) - f(x)}{d}$. In your case you let $d$ be $1$ second and that's why the thing you computed is not matching up to the derivative. $d$ going to $0$ is what makes it instantaneous!

Comment: Based on the suggestions I edited the question. I think I kind of understand the point that @joseville and John made. Thanks

Comment: @AlgTop1854 I guess that is the source of my confusion, continuous increase over time, it is probably one of the conditions for derivatives to work as it should.

Comment: I suggest before you get into problems that include another variable and the chain rule, you spend some time on the very definition of the derivative of a function of one variable as a limit of difference quotients which underlies "instantaneous rate of change", geometrically that would be tangent line to a curve as limit of secant lines; it's fine that you are teaching this to yourself but this is so fundamental you need to be sure about it before applying it to anything else.  ANY good basic text book on first-year calculus will cover this in detail.

Comment: I added a formal answer since your question gave context, what you tried and where you were stuck.  Suggestion is to spend some time on how the derivative of a single variable function arises as a limit.

Comment: I made a Desmos to illustrate how the $f'(x)$, the derivative of $f$ at $x$ is the slope of the line tangent to the graph $f$ at $x$. It might help: http://tiny.cc/jose-calc.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To illustrate the discussion in the comments, view difference quotients as an approximation to the derivative.

In this case:

$$\frac{dA}{dt} \approx \frac{\Delta A}{\Delta x} \frac{\Delta x}{\Delta t}$$

Since $\frac{\Delta x}{\Delta t} = \frac{dx}{dt} = 2$ with $\Delta x =2$ when $\Delta t =1$ you will get 28.

Now try $\Delta t = \frac12$ then $\frac14$  or smaller and you should see this expression heading to $24$.